# Calculate Employee Length of Service with Company

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below measure but it isnt producing the correct results.

I would like to show the length of service an employee has been with the business. The below measure isnt producing the correct outcome. If an employee is still with the business and started on 03/12/2018, this is showing as 1 year instead of 2 years. If an employee hasnt started with the company yet but a record exists, this is showing as -1 whereas i would like to show this as 0.

I will then need to show the average length of service by gender once the measure is correct.

I have a date table which i select the month year to run the data for that month and an employee table with employee name, start date, end date etc..

```
Employee LOS =
IF(
    ISBLANK(MAX(Query1[DATE_OF_LEAVING])),
    DATEDIFF(
        MAX(Query1[DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT]),
        MAX('Date'[Date]),
        YEAR
    ),
    DATEDIFF(
        MAX(Query1[DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT]),
        MAX(Query1[DATE_OF_LEAVING]),
        YEAR
    )
)
```

Thanks

Yasir

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using MAX('Date'[Date]) instead of Today()? Your Date table might have max date which is either very earlier or later date compare to Today. That case you will not get your expected output.

You can check what MAX('Date'[Date]) actually return using a Measure. Then check the Year is appropriate considering your joining date or not.

Comment: Hi, i have a slicer which i use to select the month year column from the date table. This is used to select data for that period

Comment: it should work that case. can you show some sample data from both table?

Comment: the date table is just date, monthyear columns 

employee table is employee name, start date, end date, gender, dob etc

Comment: Is there any relation between tables?

Comment: no there isnt. I have managed to get this working by tweaking the dax measure. Thanks for getting back to my query